# is their any default DATABASE for developing iOS native application?

Tags: ios, database

Its seems to be a silly question but I need your help as I am a beginner to iOS coding.

(1) My question is I need to know whether iOS have any default DATABASE or not. If yes can you share those links to me.
(2) If not can you suggest most popular database which can handle more than 50MB of data in iPad (Client side).

Thank You,

Madhav

What is the maximum size limit for storing the values in SQLite database for ios? 
As per my requirement I need to store more than 50MB of database.Can you suggest which database will allow more than 50MB of database in iPad (Client side).

Is there any Size limit for SQLite Database? As I am hydride app developer by using Phonegap plugins. But I am able to store only 50MB of data by using SQLite database.

Comment: Please [do some basic research](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=ios+database) before posting such a question.

Comment: This will help you - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-TP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people I know decide on using Sqlite.  Depending on your use case you may want to research:

1. CoreData backed by sqlite
2. FMDB - More low level than CoreData but comes with some performance improvements.
3. Write your own wrapper based on available c interface.

References:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: `sqlite` is not a default database.

Comment: @Kampai Sure it is. sqlite is a standard client-side database engine that comes with iOS.

Comment: @rmaddy - We can not say as default, I don't find that Apple has mention `sqlite` as default database to use. It is an option.

Comment: @Kampai if you use CoreData you have 4 options for a backing store: XML, Sqlite, Atomic and InMemory.  Most people opt for sqlite. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html

Comment: @GregoryFurmanek & @rmaddy - I do follow to store data in `sqlite`. But what I am saying is that we can not say it is a default database.

Comment: @Kampai What's your definition of "default database"? To me, the OP wants to know what standard database can be used in iOS apps. sqlite is that database. That's the default database engine that comes with iOS.

Comment: @rmaddy: Ok lets drop this one, it will lead us to no way :). Back to the OP's problem for 50MB data i think it is better to use Core data. What's your call?

Comment: @Kampai - the size of the data is less relevant than the access patterns.  If you need low level access because you need to modify significant number of records you may benefit from using FMDB.